# Differential equation on half-life isotope decay

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently working on some Differential Calculus, and I'm having a [bit of trouble](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166574/how-can-i-persuade-my-friends-to-join-stack-exchange/166590#166590) with the following question.

> The half-life of an isotope is 150 years. Use this information to
>   determine the differential equation that describes the mass as a
>   function of time. In other words m' = km where k is a constant and
>   m(t) is the mass after t years.
>
> Use the information given to find k, then solve this equation. Use the
>   solution to determine how long it takes for an initial amount to decay
>   to 15% of the original.

For what I know so far, I know little to nothing on the matter.  My professor has failed to elaborate on the subject whatsoever, and I've been googling this to try and answer it.

I think I'm supposed to use this question, but I'm not sure if it's the right one...

```
http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?dm(t)/dt%20=%20-k*m(t)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  If you start with 1 unit of the isotope at time $0$, you have $\frac 12$ after $150$ years.  Do you know how to solve $m'=km$?  That should give you an equation that (with this data) lets you determine $k$.  Now put that $k$ into your solution and find the time when the amount is $0.15$.

Added:  your equation is the correct differential equation.  The solution is $m(t)=m(0)\exp(-kt)$ as the derivative of $\exp(-kt)$ is $-k \exp(-kt)$

Comment: I don't know how to solve this m′=km exactly. Like I said, my professor did a shoddy job and didn't really explain..anything at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I used what you said, and came out with 410.5

Comment: @Retrosaur: I didn't fire up the calculator, but a half-life of 150 years says we have one eighth (0.125) left after 450 years, so it looks right.

Comment: Also, thanks for the quick response!